# How to deselect an invisible cell in a custom layout collection view?

Tags: ios, swift

Fetching the invisible cell may or may not gets the cell, even if the index position is not null.

Summary: I've tried selecting and deselecting logic inside shouldSelectItemAt function. Selection goes well. But upon selecting a new cell, the previously selected cell needed to be deselected. As I am using custom collection view layout, I doubt the problem is occurring due to reusability of cells.

Code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
if(collectionView == customContentCollectionView){
let cell:MyContentCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)! as! MyCollectionViewController.MyContentCell

// DESELECTION CODE
if(previouslySelectedIndex != nil){
                                    // following line is error prone (executes but may or may not fetch the cell, sometimes deselect sometimes doesnt)
                                    let prevCell = try collectionView.cellForItem(at: previouslySelectedIndex) as? MyCollectionViewController.MyContentCell

                                    // Also tried with this following (executes but fails sometimes, in case not fetching the cell)
                                    //let prevCell = try collectionView.cellForItem(at: previouslySelectedIndex)! as! MyCollectionViewController.MyContentCell

                                    // Tried this one as well, fetching the previously selected cell using datasource, not directly from collection view
                                    // let prevCell = customContentCollectionView.dataSource?.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAt: previouslySelectedIndex) as? MyCollectionViewController.MyContentCell

                                    prevCell?.shapeLayer.strokeColor = bubbleBorder.cgColor
                                    prevCell?.shapeLayer.fillColor = bubbleFill.cgColor
                                    prevCell?.shapeLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
                                    prevCell?.labelCount.textColor = bubbleBorder
}

// SELECTION CODE HERE GOES PRETTY WELL
...
previouslySelectedIndex = indexPath
}
```

N.B. : I am using CustomUICollectionViewFlowLayout, I need to use only shouldSelectItemAt function. No other function for selection and deselection.

Comment: :I have updated my answer Please have a look and lemme know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
let prevCell = try collectionView.cellForItem(at: previouslySelectedIndex) as? MyCollectionViewController.MyContentCell
```

returns nil because if user scrolled collectionView cell might have been reused for some other indexPath and hence returns nil.

So you should not ask for cell from `collectionView` rather you should ask datasource

```
let cell = self.collectionView?.dataSource?.collectionView(self.collectionView!, cellForItemAt: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))
```

Other approach would be to use `prepareForReuse` to reset the cell states before it gets reused. `prepareForReuse` sounds more legitimate solution to me though :)

**EDIT:**

On a second thought though above code will return the cell, updating the UI of cell not loaded/reused will result in adverse effects. Rather what you can do is in `shouldSelectItemAt` update the UI of the deselected cell only if cell is available

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        if(collectionView == customContentCollectionView){
            let cell:MyContentCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)! as! MyCollectionViewController.MyContentCell

            // DESELECTION CODE
            if(previouslySelectedIndex != nil){
                // following line is error prone (executes but may or may not fetch the cell, sometimes deselect sometimes doesnt)
                if let prevCell = try collectionView.cellForItem(at: previouslySelectedIndex) as? MyCollectionViewController.MyContentCell {

                    // Also tried with this following (executes but fails sometimes, in case not fetching the cell)
                    //let prevCell = try collectionView.cellForItem(at: previouslySelectedIndex)! as! MyCollectionViewController.MyContentCell

                    // Tried this one as well, fetching the previously selected cell using datasource, not directly from collection view
                    // let prevCell = customContentCollectionView.dataSource?.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAt: previouslySelectedIndex) as? MyCollectionViewController.MyContentCell

                    prevCell?.shapeLayer.strokeColor = bubbleBorder.cgColor
                    prevCell?.shapeLayer.fillColor = bubbleFill.cgColor
                    prevCell?.shapeLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
                    prevCell?.labelCount.textColor = bubbleBorder
                }
            }

            // SELECTION CODE HERE GOES PRETTY WELL
                previouslySelectedIndex = indexPath
        }
    }
```

If let added above should take care of ensuring the you update the UI of cell to deselect it only if it is available.

Now implement `prepareForReuse` in cell

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    //reset all the fields of cell
    self.shapeLayer.strokeColor = bubbleBorder.cgColor
    self.shapeLayer.fillColor = bubbleFill.cgColor
    self.shapeLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.0
    self.labelCount.textColor = bubbleBorder
}
```

Finally in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
     //your code to create cell n all

     if(indexPath == previouslySelectedIndex) {
         //your code to select the cell
     }

     return cell
 }
```

Hope this helps